# How to use `domain` module properly in Node.js

Tags: node.js, error-handling

What is the proper way of using [domain](http://nodejs.org/api/domain.html) module in NodeJS applications?

1. Wrap up the code blocks with the domain instance like how we use `try-catch` blocks? If yes, should we create new instances of domain each time for each separated block?
2. Wrap up the main function with the domain `run` method? If yes, is that really sufficient for an enterprise application for example?

P.S. Is there any well-known open-source node project with an extensive use of `domain` module where I can study their code?

P.P.S. Looking at the node documentation and tutorials, I see that almost all of them just simply wrapped up the main function within the domain's `run` method, however as far as I can see they are mostly copying each other. I basically can't see how people use `domain` module in different situations (what I see is mostly a copy of node documentation with couple of minor changes)

Comment: I'm on the same boat. Please update if you find something useful.

Comment: @SamSerious sure, I'll keep you posted

Comment: Perhaps this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17498222/writing-domain-aware-functions-in-nodejs) is helpful.